# BLE connection fails on Android - Invalid pin or passkey

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I am working on a mobile app that connects to accessories over BLE. The app runs on Android as well as iOS.

I have a Raspberry Pi that is running a BLE server app.

When my Android app tries to connect to Pi over BLE, the connectivity just fails. I see a system notification popping up that Bluetooth connection failed because of an invalid pin or passkey.

However, my iOS app seems to connect just fine. There is no PIN or passkey requested.

I have tried Android testing with Pixel 2 as well as Pixel 3. The OS version is 10.

My Android app used to work fine until a few months ago. I feel it must be a recent change in Android OS.

I am wondering if anyone else has seen such a problem. Thanks.